# Getting "No such module" error after running POD LIB LINT

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, lint, twitterkit

I'm trying to create a POD but when I run `pod lib lint` or `pod spec lint`, I get the next output:

> `XXXXXX/LoginService/LoginService.swift:10:8: error: no such module
>   'TwitterKit' import TwitterKit
>          ^
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileSwift normal x86_64 
>   XXXXXX/LoginService/LoginService.swift    CompileSwiftSources normal
>   x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (2 failures)  ->
>   LoginService (0.1.0)
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/danielfernandez/Documents/tekton_projects/LoginService/LoginService/LoginService.swift:10:8:
>   error: no such module 'TwitterKit'`

I don't know why, because If I build my project there is no errors, I'm using the TwitterKit without any problem.

This is my first time trying to create a pod. I used cocoapods to install Twitter Kit and my Xcode Version is 8.3.3

This is my POD SPEC:
[image]

If I put the s.dependency, I get this error: The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries

If I use --use-libraries I get this error: Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!`

This is my Podfile:
[image]

Comment: Can you share you `.podspec`. It's likely that you didn't include the `TwitterKit` lib in your `.podspec`.

Comment: Hi, I just update my question with my Pod Spec and Podfile. I wasn't including the TwitterKit in my spec (s.dependency) but now I have another errors. Do you know what can be making those?